# unique optimal point of $f_0(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i)$?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the following convex program:

\begin{aligned}
\textrm{minimize} & \quad f_0(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i) \\
\textrm{subject to} & \quad a^Tx=b
\end{aligned}

where $a\in \mathbb{R}^n, b\in \mathbb R$, and $f_i:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ are differentiable and strictly convex.  It is stated in Boyd & Vandenberghe's book (Example 5.4) that if there exists an $x_0 \in \mathrm{dom}\:f_0$ such that $a^Tx_0=b$, then the convex program has a unique optimal point.  I don't quite see why.  Does someone know the reason?

It appear to me that a counter-example could be: $f_0(x_1, x_2)=e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}$, subject to $x_1-x_2=0$.  Then $\mathrm{dom}\:f_0=\mathbb R^2$ and includes the line $x_1-x_2=0$.  And the optimal value of this program would be $0$, but is never attained, isn't it?  I'd appreciate it, if someone can point out where I missed.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Indeed. *If* a minimum exists, it is unique, but you have offered a valid example where one does not exist.

Comment: @MichaelGrant, Why don't you post an answer so that he could mark it as answer and the question will be marked as solved?